# Access the 2D array indices based on the value of another 1d array?

Tags: python, list

```
DV=[[1,0], [1,1], [0, 0], [0,1]]
V=[0,2,3]
```

What is the convenient way to access the value of `DV` based on the value of `V`?

for example

```
DV[0][0] [0][1] 
DV[2][0] [0][1] 
DV[3][0] [3][1]
```

Comment: What does this example mean?  How is `V` being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess something like this?

```
>>> DV = [[1,0], [1,1], [0, 0], [0,1]]
>>> V = [0,2,3]
>>> [DV[i] for i in V]
[[1, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1]]
```

Edit: Not sure if this is what you are looking for from the comments

```
>>> # remove index from V if it's [0, 0] in DV?
>>> [i for i in V if sum(DV[i]) != 0]
[0, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks. Similar. However, Instead of accessing all, can I access row by row for example 0 first then 2 then 3. If there is any 1 in DV it will keep the value otherwise delete it from V. In this case, The final value of V will be V=[0,3]  as the 3rd value is [0,0]

Comment: I don’t understand what you are asking here, what is the relation between V and DV? What do you mean by removing values from V? Is there any expected output?

Comment: Can you post the code which gives this error?